# Set variable value in javascript from wicket

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

I am trying to set a value to a variable defined in a javascript file from wicket.

Basically I want to pass the set the value of any variable to handlerAjax.getCallbackUrl() so that I could then use that variable in **wicketAjaxGet**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it.

Wicket Page Component:

```
Label myScript = new Label("myScript", "url = '" + behave.getCallbackUrl() + "';");
myScript.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
add(myScript);
```

Add this in html header part

```
<script type="text/javascript" wicket:id="myScript"></script>
```

actual call:

```
var wcall = wicketAjaxGet(url + '', function() { }, function() { });
```